# Creating Link to Same Page with Request Parameters in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, httprequest

How might one use the url_for or link_to helpers to create a link to the same page passing along all GET parameters?

I have a search page which accepts multiple parameters as filters to hide certain results. For example, `search.html?query=abc&people=1&groups=0` would search for all items containing 'abc' that aren't groups. I would therefore like a link which toggles these filters, passing the rest of the parameters unchanged to the current page. In the above example, links would be created to `search.html?query=abc&people=1&groups=1` and `search.html?query=abc&people=0&groups=0`.

I am wondering if there is any way to specify 'this' as a route, such that if the route or page changed, the code wouldn't have to.

Moreover, how can one pass all parameters to the helper? `$sf_params` can be used to access all the parameters, and the 'query_string' property can be passed to the helper, but is there any method of combining the two short of creating the string manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET parameters can be passed to a `link_to` method as an array in the third argument, or `url_for` in the second. This is illustrated as follows:

```
link_to('Text to display', 'routename', array('group' => 0, 'people' => 1), $link_attributes);
url_for('routename', array('group' => 0, 'people' => 1));
```

This is hidden in the source code. Here, `$params` is the list of GET parameters, and `$options` HTML attributes to add to the tag.

```
function link_to2($name, $routeName, $params, $options = array())
function url_for2($routeName, $params = array(), $absolute = false)
```

The `$sf_params` function can be converted to a suitable array for passing with `getAll()`. See the documentation [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfParameterHolder). Note that this is different from previous versions of Symfony. Also be aware you might have to call `getRawValue()` from within a template:

```
$params = $sf_params->getRawValue()->getAll();
```

`$sf_context->getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentRouteName()` can then be passed as $routeName to get the current route. *Thanks to [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244932/tom) for this*

Comment: Maybe "$sf_context->getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentRouteName()" for the "this" (with @ appended in front).

Comment: @Tom That seems to make it ignore the parameters passed, unfortunately.

Comment: Yep, on its own it would. I was just thinking about using that as the $routeName component in your example above.

Comment: @Tom Ah yeah, it works without `@` appended on the front. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

put vars in hidden form data types to pass them on

```
<form action="page.php" method="GET">
<input name="people" type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['people'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
<input name="groups" type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['groups'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
<input name="query" type="text" value="some_data">
<input name="send" type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am not looking for a form to send data, but a link.

Comment: Yes, but the links that toggle these filters would not be.